# php: how to replace a letter NOT following a backslash

Tags: php, regex

hi i want to replace all "e" in a string with "-" which are NOT following a backslash
so "hello" should be -> "h-llo" but "h\ello" should be "hello" any ideas if this is possible with a single regex?

Comment: What should `"h\ere"` look like after being replaced (one `e` has a backslash but the other does not)? Should it become `"her-"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way but to use the `e` flag if you need to combine both regexes since the replacement is different.

```
preg_replace('/(\\\\?e)/e', "'\\1'=='e'?'-':'e'", $str);
```

(Usage: http://www.ideone.com/S2uiS)

There is no need to use regex though. [The `strtr` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) is capable of performing this kind of replacement.

```
strtr($str, array('\\e' => 'e', 'e' => '-'));
```

(Usage: http://www.ideone.com/yg93g)

Comment: Would give another +1 for `strtr()` if I could.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure that the character before the e is not a backslash:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(?<!\\)e/', "-", $string);
```

Comment: thx for your fast answer! there was an error thrown by php i have changed it to preg_replace('/(?<!\\\)e/', '-', $str); and it works! thx! but "t\est" now stays "t\est" what i want is "t\est" -> "test". i know i can do this in a second replace function. but is it possible to integrate it in your regex?

Comment: No, you need a second replace operation for this.

Comment: You don't even need a second regex for that, just use `str_replace('\\', '', $your_string)`

Comment: Or even `stripslashes($string)`.